# Powering MCU from VBUS without damaging 5 V regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, esp32

My board is powered normally from a 12 V input through a buck converter (5 V) K7805-500 into an AMS1117 (3.3 V)

When programming I will need to power the board from VBUS (5 V). How can I tap into the input of the AMS1117 without damaging the K7805 (5 V) regulator/buck converter?

I don't really want to put a diode on the output of the 5 V regulator as the voltage drop may be an issue.

I've heard that I can run a Schottky from output to input.

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Schottky diode has a forward voltage of only around 0.3V, so you should be able to just put one in series with your buck converter's output and another in series with your VBUS input, tying the cathodes together before going into the AMS1117-3.3's input. This will isolate the two supplies so that you can use either.

The AMS1117-3.3 has a dropout voltage of 1.1V, so you can get away with an input voltage as low as 4.4V, which gives you enough headroom to use a Schottky diode.

A slightly more efficient (but more complex) solution would be a MOSFET ideal diode setup. You can search for "MOSFET ideal diode power supply ORing" and find a ton of resources on how to build such a design. The TL;DR is that MOSFETs can be configured to act like a diode with near-zero forward voltage drop. You need four MOSFETs (two back-to-back on each input) to implement this here, so the BOM cost will be higher than with a Schottky.

Comment: Went with two B5819 diodes seemed the easiest approach